# In _.invoke source code, what is the args' role?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, lodash

I just started to learn JS few months ago and I tried to understand what the "args" doing in "_.invoke" source code.
Is there anyone who can answer this, please?

I read mdn .apply and read other _.invoke source codes, but couldn't understand.

```
  _.invoke = function (collection, functionOrKey, args) {
    if(typeof functionOrKey === "string") {
      return _.map(collection, function(item) {
        return item[functionOrKey].apply(item, args);
      });
    }
    else return _.map(collection, function(item) {
      return functionOrKey.apply(item, args);
    });
  };
```

---

test function is like this :

```
_.invoke(['dog', 'cat'], 'toUpperCase');
      });

      it('runs the specified method on each item in the array, and returns a list of results', function() {
        var upperCasedStrings = _.invoke(['dog', 'cat'], 'toUpperCase');

        expect(upperCasedStrings).to.eql(['DOG', 'CAT']);
```

in test function, there are no 'args', why!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that's happening is you're taking an argument or array of arguments to apply to the function being used to map over the collection - all three are arguments passed to the function.

It's similar to other methods you might find in libraries like Lodash/Underscore.js - it's essentially a custom mapping function, where you pass the arguments like so:

```
let mapped = _.invoke(arr, aFunc, ["anArgument", 2]);
```

If no arguments are passed, then the function passed doesn't need arguments - `toUpperCase` doesn't need arguments, so none are needed - therefore none are passed.